# Workflow for specific file/folder

Tags: designer-workflow

I have setup some content types in a document center site on sharepoint. I have two folders, one called NDA-Contracts and one called TSM-Contracts within the main Contracts Folder. If users click New, based on the content type I have made they can choose a NDA word document or a TSM word document to fill out and save. I was wondering is there a way to have a workflow move the word document to one of those folders based on what type it is once the user hits save and gives it a name? 
Example: if a user is within the Main Contracts folder and chooses the NDA word document, fills it out and hits save as and gives it a name I would like it to save in the NDA specific folder
I am basically trying to build a cheap contract management system in sharepoint. I think I could use a Document Set but haven't figured that out yet. Wanted to start simple.

Answer (score 0):

A great way to do this is with [SharePoint's Content Organizer](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/Create-Content-Organizer-rules-to-route-documents-74dfe36d-e3d6-40b7-9a5c-beea0c84deed).

Rules can be created the move documents around based on the content types selected when uploaded.  You can route documents based on not just the content types, but also other metadata.  You can route them to folders or libraries.  You can even forward them to other sites.

Another nice write-up on this can be found [here](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/sharepoint-2010-content-organizer-part-1-a-cool-new-feature-for-managing-your-content/), [here](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/sharepoint-2010-content-organizer-part-2-the-rules-engine/) and [here](https://samlman.wordpress.com/2015/02/28/sharepoint-2010-content-organizer-part-3-the-drop-off-library/).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just thought I would mention, you could likely do this as well with a WF.  You could create a reusable WF based on a CT that gets fired when a doc is created, but I would suggest researching the Content Organizer first.  If you don't think it will work for you, let me know and I can see about helping you with doing it via WF.